# BLE Data convert to Bytearray in Python

Tags: python, bluetooth-lowenergy, ibeacon

I am getting the BLE gateway data in the below format.

```
0201061AFF4C000215E2C56DB5DFFB48D2B060D0F5A71096E027100000D7
```

When, I am manually converting it to

```
\x02\x01\x06\x1A\xFF\x4C\x00\x02\x15\xE2\xC5\x6D\xB5\xDF\xFB\x48\xD2\xB0\x60\xD0\xF5\xA7\x10\x96\xE0\x27\x10\x00\x00\xD7
```

I am able to parse it with beacontools, using parse_packet() .

However, I am unable to programatically convert the string into Hexadecimal.

Any help is much appreciated.

Code :

```
from beacontools import parse_packet

tlm_packet = b'\x02\x01\x06\x1A\xFF\x4C\x00\x02\x15\xE2\xC5\x6D\xB5\xDF\xFB\x48\xD2\xB0\x60\xD0\xF5\xA7\x10\x96\xE0\x27\x10\x00\x00\xD7'


tlm_frame = parse_packet(tlm_packet)
print(tlm_frame)
```

Works as expected.

```
data = '0201061AFF4C000215E2C56DB5DFFB48D2B060D0F5A71096E027100000D7'
tlm_frame = parse_packet(bytes(data,'utf-8'))
print(tlm_frame)
```

Doesn't work

Comment: You are having 2 slightly different hexadecimal formats and want to convert it into a third?

Comment: No, I want the first format to able to parse using beacontools function parse_packet() .

Comment: Show us your related code!

Answer (score 0):

```py
from beacontools import parse_packet

import binascii

data = '0201061AFF4C000215E2C56DB5DFFB48D2B060D0F5A71096E027100000D7'

t = binascii.unhexlify(data)


tlm_frame = parse_packet(t)

print(tlm_frame)
```